# Expresión regular para caracteres consecutivos

Tags: regex, genexus

Tengo una complicación con seguridad en contraseñas. Estoy trabajando en GeneXus con regex.

Tengo el siguiente requerimiento para validación de una contraseña. 
-no permitir que la contraseña tenga caracteres consecutivos repetidos. Es decir:

```
abc#+123 es válida
123abc#+ es válida
abbc#+123 NO es válida
abc##+123 NO es válida
abc#+1224 NO es válida
```

Estoy siguiendo la siguiente sintaxis con respecto a otras validaciones por ejemplo:

- `^(?=.*\d)\S{longitudcontraseña, }$`
  (la contraseña debe incluir numeros?)
- `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])\S{longitudcontraseña, }$`
  (la contraseña debe incluir numeros y mayúsculas)

Comment: Vale destacar que los ejemplos "válidos" no tienen letras mayúsculas, pero en tu segunda condición lo estás exigiendo.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando se quiere hacer referencia al texto con el que ya se hizo una coincidencia, se utiliza una referencia a una captura (*backreference*). Al utilizar paréntesis, el texto con el que se coincidió se guarda como referencia. Así, `\1` guarda el texto de la coincidencia del primer grupo (el primer par de paréntesis, de izquierda a derecha), `\2` la del segundo, y así sucesivamente hasta `\9` (o más dependiendo del lenguaje).

**2 caracteres consecutivos**. Para detectar 2 caracteres repetidos consecutivamente, usamos

```
(.)\1
```

**N caracteres consecutivos**. Si quisieras que coincida con más de 2, digamos 4 caracteres, estaría repetido 3 veces (o así para cualquier N):

```
(.)\1{3}
```

**Que no tenga caracteres repetidos consecutivos**. Esto, lo incluimos dentro de una aserción negativa (*negative lookahead*), buscando que no esté presente en la contraseña. Esta expresión sólo coincide si no tiene caracteres repetidos consecutivos:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)
```

**Junto al resto de las condiciones**. Sumado a tu expresión, nos queda:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*(.)\1)\S{longitudcontraseña,}
```

- Obviamente, `longitudcontraseña` es un número.
- Y vale destacar que tus ejemplos "válidos" no tienen una letra mayúscula, pero deberían.

Demo con largo mínimo 6: https://regex101.com/r/wvB0jr/1/

Comment: ¡Brillante! - Sólo una pregunta, ¿la expresión resultante es compatible con [tag:java] y/o [tag:c#]?

Comment: @Paul Sí. Usa construcciones presentes en prácticamente todos los dialectos de regex ([tabla de compatibilidad](http://regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html))

Answer (score -1):

```
// &password es la clave ingresada
&largo = len(&password)
&tieneminusculas = 0
&tienemayusculas = 0
&tienenumeros = 0
&tienesimbolos = 0
&posicion = 1
&caracter = ''
&repite = 0
do while (&posicion < &largo ) and (&repite = 0) 
  &caracternuevo  = subsr(&password, &posicion,1)
  if &caracter = &caracternuevo  
        &repite = 1
   endif
   if &tienemayusculas + &tieneminusculas + &tienenumeros + &tienesimbolos < 4
   do case
        case &caracter in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
            &tienenumeros = 1
        case &caracter in ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g',.....,'x','y','z')
            &tieneminusculas = 1
        case &caracter in ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G',.....,'X','Y','Z')
            &tieneminusculas = 1
        case &caracter in ('!','@','#','$','%','&',.....,'*','/','-')
            &tienesimbolos = 1
    EndCase 
    endif
enddo

if (&tienemayusculas + &tieneminusculas + &tienenumeros + &tienesimbolos = 4 ) and &repite = 0
   msg('PASSWORD VALIDO')
else
    error('PASSWORD INVALIDO')
endif
```

Comment: Creo que podrías agregar algo explicando un poco de qué se trata tu solución... Especialmente porque la pregunta apunta a obtener una expresión regular, y no estás usando ninguna en tu solución.

Comment: Además, ¿en qué momento estás incrementando `&posicion`? ¿No entraría en un bucle infinito? ¿Lo probaste al código?