# Expresiones Regulares para contraseña fuerte

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito validar que una contraseña cumpla con los siguientes 4 parámetros:

1. 1 Mayúscula
2. 1 Minúscula
3. 2 Números
4. Solo de exactamente 8 caracteres
5. No puede haber espacios en blanco
6. Y no repetir un mismo carácter 4 veces (ejemplo: `aBc12aaa` es inválida)

Con el ejemplo de [una respuesta del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75926/127), ya tengo las primeras 5 reglas,
solo falta aplicar el punto 6:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1})\S{8}$
```

Comment: Entonces, no puede tener espacios? Ni menos, ni más de 8 caracteres? Eso parece según tu expresión

Comment: edité tu pregunta según lo que se interpretaba de tu expresión. Si hay algo incorrecto, no dudes en editarlo o comentarlo.

Comment: @Alfonso Si alguna pregunta resolvió tu problema no dudes en aceptarla con el botón de palomita que aparece a la izquierda de la respuesta

Answer (score 7):

Expresión regular:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.{0,4}(.)(?:.*\1){3})\S{8}$
```

Notas:

- La expresión regular responde a lo que preguntaste, pero deberías saber que esto va en contra de todas las recomendaciones de reglas de contraseñas.

  ¿Por qué forzar a que sean 8 caracteres? Si es mucho más seguro una contraseña más larga.

  ¿Por qué mayúsculas entre A y Z? Es mucho más seguro que ingrese 5 caracteres chinos.

  ¿Por qué no se aceptan espacios? Es mucho más seguro el estribillo de mi canción preferida.

  > Sobre este tema, te recomiendo leer estos 2 artículos (en inglés):
  >
  > - [Password Rules Are Bullshit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/) (Jeff Atwood)
  > - [Passwords Evolved: Authentication Guidance for the Modern Era](https://www.troyhunt.com/passwords-evolved-authentication-guidance-for-the-modern-era/) (Troy Hunt)
- No es necesario repetir `(?:.*[A-Z]){1}` 1 vez. Es lo mismo que `.*[A-Z]`.
- La parte que te interesaba, para evitar que use 4 caracteres iguales es

  ```
  ^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){3})
  ```

  Es una [inspección negativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead), que captura en el grupo 1 (entre paréntesis) a un caracter cualquiera con `(.)`, y luego busca la coincidencia de ese mismo caracter 3 veces con `(?:.*\1){3}`, ya que `\1` coincide con la captura del grupo 1.

  Además, como el primer caracter de la repetición sólo puede aparecer hasta el 5to lugar, lo limitamos a:

  ```
  ^(?!.{0,4}(.)(?:.*\1){3})
  ```

  Podés leer una explicación más detallada en [*Expresión regular para caracteres consecutivos*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99857/127).

Demo:

```js
var politicaContrasenna = /^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.{0,4}(.)(?:.*\1){3})\S{8}$/,
    inpClave = document.getElementById('clave'),
    inpOk = document.getElementById('ok');

inpClave.addEventListener(
    'input',
    function (evt) {
        if (politicaContrasenna.test(inpClave.value)) {
            inpOk.innerText = 'válida';
        } else {
            inpOk.innerText = 'inválida';
        }
    }
);
```

```css
#clave {
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<input id="clave"
       placeholder="8 caracteres, con 2 dígitos, 1 may, 1 min, sin repetir 1 caracter 4 veces, sin espacios">
<pre   id="ok" />
```