# ¿Expresión regular para contraseña segura con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular que exige al menos:

- un carácter numérico,
- uno del alfabeto en minúscula,
- uno en mayúscula,
- uno especial y,
- entre 8 y 16 caracteres de rango:

  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\u0021-\u002b\u003c-\u0040])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])\S{8,16}$/

Estoy haciendo esta prueba:

```
const securePasswordRegEx = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\u0021-\u002b\u003c-\u0040])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])\S{8,16}$/;

const password = 'Victor.123456'
console.log({length: password.length})

console.log(securePasswordRegEx.test(password));
```

Y siempre me sale falso, he probado de todo y nunca hace match...

Por ejemplo, usé esta página: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/)

Y probé: `Nombre.1234`, lo cual cumple con todo y no funciona.

También probé esta expresión:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,16}$"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tampoco hace match...

Comment: Entre al sitio por curiosidad y probé tu expresión regular, "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,16}$"  de entrada no acepta ni numero, ni letra ni minúscula ni mayúscula. Lo unico que te puedo recomendar es que vayas construyendo la expresión carácter por carácter que vas a permitir ingresar  te pongo un ejemplo simple /[a-zA-Z]+/g tomada de la misma pagina permite ingresar tanto letras minúsculas como mayúsculas.

Comment: Sí, es raro, se supone que es la solución de una pregunta similar acá... :/ Intentaré construirla.

Comment: Solo trata de verificar cada entrada caracter por caracter asi te daras cuenta en donde esta el error, la bondad de la pagina que ingresaste es que te indica caracter a caracter si hace o no mach, asi lo probe yo, escribi una letra , otra, un numero y nada, desde la primer captura no pasa

Comment: yo construí ahi esta expresión var expreg =/^[0]{4}[0-9]{8}[0-9]{4}$/; es muy sencilla pero muy eficiente traducido 4 ceros, del 0 al 9  en secuencia hasta en 8 posiciones y del 0 al 9 hasta  4 posiciones  esta genial, si falta un numero no pasa con esto valido la captura de un codigo de barras tanto con pistola como desde el teclado.

Answer (score 1):

Me apoyé de la respuesta de esta pregunta: [Expresiones Regulares para contraseña fuerte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125685/expresiones-regulares-para-contrase%C3%B1a-fuerte)

```
/^(?=(?:.*\d))(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.,*!?¿¡/#$%&])\S{8,64}$/
```

- Al menos un número 0-9
- Al menos una mayúscula
- Al menos una minúscula
- Al menos un carácter especial (.,*!?¿¡/#$%&)
- Longitud mínima de 8 caracteres, 64 máxima
- No acepta espacios

Comment: Ya lo probe en la pagina y tampoco acepta nada, en base a lo que expones en tu pregunta hice de manera rudimentaria la expresion regular, ya es cuestion que añadas el aspecto de seguridad que buscas.  Esta es la expresion regular que construir en base a tus requerimientos: \d{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[@$!%*?&]{1}[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,16}  si lo pruebas hace macth. Saludos

Comment: La que puse anterior si aceptaba, solo que no aceptaba los caracteres especiales que necesitaba, ya la actualicé y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Excelente!!! cuidate!!!.